# Rename in Post-Build Event when Deploying Web-Role to Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, post-build-event

I have a big WCF project which is structured in many sub projects (website in web role, backend, WPF client, client library etc.). Each of these projects has 3 config files:

- app.config - for local testing
- app.release.config - with productive service addresses
- app.test.config - with service addresses of test server

These files are renamed using post-build events according to the current solution configuration (Debug/Release/Test). So the post-build event in the different projects looks like this (except in the web-role project it's "web.config" and not "app.config"):

```
if not "Release"=="$(ConfigurationName)" goto :nocopyrelease
del "$(TargetPath).config"
copy "$(ProjectDir)\App.release.config" "$(TargetPath).config"
:nocopyrelease

if not "Test"=="$(ConfigurationName)" goto :nocopytest
del "$(TargetPath).config"
copy "$(ProjectDir)\App.test.config" "$(TargetPath).config"
:nocopytest
```

When I build these projects the renaming is done according to the current build configuration and everything is working as expected, so I'm sure the build events are fine like they are now. But as soon as I publish to azure or package the "Azure Cloud Service" which has the web role in it, the renaming is not done when I check the csx-Folder or the content of the cspkg-Package.

Is there any smart way I can use different configs depending on the selected build configuration when publishing to Azure? What I did so far is renaming the config files in all the projects before publishing. But this is a rather annoying task and is prone to mistakes. There has to be a better way...

I thought getting this to work with solution configuration and build-events would be the easiest way, as changing the solution configuration in the drop down between Test/Debug/Release would handle all the config renaming if it was working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put your Post-Build Event?

You need to put your Post-Build Event on your cloud service, not your WCF project, see the attached screenshot:
 [image]

Right click > Properties > Build Event